# No Recycle Bin in new partition

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, recycle-bin

I have an old computer with Windows 8.
I had the OS partition `C`, and a data partition `D`.
I [shrank](https://superuser.com/questions/1017764/how-can-i-shrink-a-windows-10-partition/1060508#1060508) `C`, making some 80Gb room between `C` and `D`.
I created one more partition with *Disk Management* -> *Create Simple Volume*.
Now I see that both `C` and `D` have their hidden `$RECYCLE.BIN` directories, which I assume they store files/directories deleted from each partition.
But my new `F` partition does not have that.

This brings a few questions:

1. Would I have a recycle bin for files I delete from `F`?
2. If so, where would those files go?
3. If not, what should I do to have that?

PS: just in case anyone asks, I am not upgrading to 8.1 because I have problem [Windows Store says my PC isn't connected to the internet](https://superuser.com/questions/499792/windows-store-says-my-pc-isnt-connected-to-the-internet)

Comment: I believe a recycle bin folder is only created when needed (file deleted).

Comment: Also, drives seen as removable may not have Recycle Bin. Be sure the F: drive is shown as internal, not removable.

Comment: @DanielB - Ok, that is easy to try, I would create a file and remove it.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - And how would i do that? Thanks.

Comment: See https://www.easeus.com/computer-instruction/windows-10-thinks-my-hard-drive-is-removable.html

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio - Do what exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound - "Be sure the F: drive is shown as internal, not removable."
I rebooted now, and both `$RECYCLE.BIN` and `System Volume Information` are present now. I didn't even have to remove a file.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio - Seems you have answered your own question.  If it were a removable drive, it couldn't have a recycle bin, and it would be connected by USB.   [Is There a Way to See if a Hard Drive is Internal or External?](https://superuser.com/questions/1115105/is-there-a-way-to-see-if-a-hard-drive-is-internal-or-external)

Answer (score 0):

It seems rebooting is all that is needed.